# Импорт n-количества файлов в matlab

Tags: импорт, matlab

Имеется некоторое количество (1000) файлов формата 0adc.log ... 999adc.log. Необходимо импортировать их, как я понимаю, с помощью цикла, в среду matlab. Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
files = dir('*.log');
for i=1:length(files)
load(files(i).name, '-ascii');
end
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]